# Animate flexbox columns on data refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an array of values which I wish to display in columns, each with a max of 2 rows. I've been able to achieve the layout I need using css flex box, but when the data is refreshed, the animation snaps to the new values and looks *clunky*. I would like each column to slide in/out as the width changes.

I'm struggling to achieve any animation when the text (and subsequent) width of each `item` changes. Adding `transition: all 1s linear` to the `item` doesn't have any effect.

I've simplified the example as far as possible below.

Is it possible to achieve the animation I desire? Or do I need to look for other options, possibly using `<table>'`'s

```js
initWords = function() {
  words = generateWords(9, 10);
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    $('.container').append(`
      <div class="item">
        <label>${i + 1}</label>
        <span id="${i}">${words[i]}</span>
      </div>`);
  }
}

refreshWords = function() {
  words = generateWords(9, 10);
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    $("#"+i).text(words[i]);
  }
}

generateWords = function(num, maxSize) {
  let words = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    words.push(Math.random().toString(36).slice(
      Math.floor((Math.random() * maxSize) + 1) * -1));
  }
  return words;
}

initWords();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.item label,
.item span {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<button onclick="refreshWords()">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Which effects are you trying to achieve, animate the width?

Comment: Yeah, the width. I'm looking for it to slide in/out

Comment: I guess you can check the width of each item with jquery, css can't animate auto value.

Answer (score 1):

Bit hackish, but something like this i guess.

```
initWords = function() {
  words = generateWords(9, 10);
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    $('.container').append(
      <div class="item">
        <label class="label-text">${i + 1}</label>
        <span class="item-text" id="${i}">${words[i]}</span>
      </div>);
  }
}

refreshWords = function() {
  words = generateWords(9, 10);
  toggle = !toggle;
  var d = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  var m = document.querySelectorAll('.label-text');
  var k = document.querySelectorAll('.item-text');

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    $("#" + i).text(words[i]);
    var width = m[i].clientWidth + k[i].clientWidth + 25;
    d[i].style.width = `${width}px`;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyh3fabq/20

Comment: Thanks. I agree, it is kinda hacky, and I was hoping for a clean css solution. Will still give you an upvote though